# Do i have the right to use Ubuntu on a laptop with preinstalled Windows 7(which is deinstalled for some reason)?

Tags: windows-7, legal

I read the Windows reinstallation terms and it says license on preinstalled Windows copy allows to reinstall,recover or use only this preinstalled Windows copy.Does that mean I am not allowed to use Ubuntu on this laptop?It serves me just fine,but I still want this Windows copy to be reinstalled.A tough question.

Comment: All the answers below are tentative: only a copyright lawyer should answer this. Not every EULA is valid. It also depends on the country you are in. "but I still want this Windows copy to be reinstalled" windows 7 is end of life. Microsoft wants you to purchase a new license for Windows 10 :) All in all: if you want to install Ubuntu go for it.  Oh and that EULA can only be enforced if you ever accepted it ;)

Comment: By the way,what I read is actually on Microsoft Community by someone who posted it.

Answer (score 7):

What you read means that the license you have is for the preinstalled Windows copy and not for any other Windows copy. Microsoft cannot give or revoke licenses concerning other operating systems and it cannot force anyone to use Windows exclusively.

You can get rid of Windows or use Ubuntu too anytime you like.

Answer (score 4):

No, it means that you cannot use that Windows licence on another PC.

You have every right to install what you like on your laptop and that includes ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

Of course you can use Ubuntu on your own device!

Actually, you shouldn't even consider using Windows 7 anymore since it has been an EOL operating system for over a year.  This means that it has known security vulnerabilities that will never be patched.  Microsoft doesn't want you to use it either.

Ubuntu is a good replacement for Windows 7 since you can use a current version of Ubuntu that still gets security updates.

Comment: I still think Windows 7 can be supported.That means I still have a Windows 7 reinstallation chance.

Comment: No, Windows 7 is absolutely not supported any longer.  If you want to use Windows you need to upgrade to another version. See: https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/windows-7-end-of-life-support-information ; https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-7-support-ended-on-january-14-2020-b75d4580-2cc7-895a-2c9c-1466d9a53962

Comment: Sad for me,but I so love,when someone gives a link to a site with reliable info.

Comment: By the way,any version of legally licensed Windows is just a great thing for me.

Comment: Maybe the HP support could reinstall Windows 7?

Comment: I think,I would like to try their help.

Comment: No they won't.  Using Windows 7 past EOL is like walking around with a target on your back.  Microsoft gave free upgrades to Windows 10 for a year and a half for all users of Windows 7 and Windows 8.  They practically beat people over the head with the upgrade notifications. That upgrade period is officially over, but perhaps you can do some research to find out if the free upgrade is still possible.

Comment: People who insist on connecting EOL Windows operating systems to the internet are a gold mine to hackers. That's because you are using software with known security vulnerabilities that will not get fixed.  There's no circumstance where it's safe to use a consumer version of Windows 7 past EOL which was well over a year ago.

Answer (score 1):

Not only are you entitled to install what you like on your machine, you could theoretically even get a refund for Windows if you didn't activate it on the machine and completely remove it.

> You might be entitled to a refund for Microsoft Windows and any other related OEM software that may also be included if you have installed Linux, a BSD, BeOS, OS/2, Solaris, NetWare, Windows NT, or another OS on a machine which came preloaded with MS-Windows*.

[LinuxMall](http://www.linuxmall.com/refund/)

This has to be done when you purchase the machine (new)

Comment: There is not a chance that MS going to give a refund. This PC was preloaded with Windows 7 so it was sold at LEAST 9 years ago...

Comment: It is ok.I do not need any refund for this.

Comment: Of course one would have to ask for the refund at the time of purchase

Answer (score 1):

Windows licence can apply only to Windows. It cannot apply to other operating systems. You are allowed to install any operating system on your hardware because it's **your** hardware.

Answer (score 0):

I would think you would even have the option to install that version of windows on a virtual machine that ONLY is run on that laptop. I always keep a Windows VM around for those rare times I need to use Windows.